# Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established when using Node-mailer

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

Hello guys I'm trying to use this function I wrote ,it was working when I used the free mailer provided by outlook, however this is the error I'm getting

> Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection
> was established
>
> at connResetException (internal/errors.js:609:14)
>
> at TLSSocket.onConnectEnd (_tls_wrap.js:1547:19)
>
> at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:420:28)
>
> at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:326:22)
>
> at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1223:12)
>
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
> {
>
> code: 'ESOCKET',
>
> path: undefined,
>
> host: 'localhost',
>
> port: undefined,
>
> localAddress: undefined,
>
> command: 'CONN'
>
> }

I thought its an unhandled promise issue so i added a return new promise, but still nothing worked :(  .

Please guys i need your help

This is the function

```
 offreEmail : function (brand,model,date,id,email){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        let readHTMLFile = function (path, callback) {
            fs.readFile(path, { encoding: 'utf-8' }, function (err, html) {
                if (err) {
                    callback(err);
                    throw err;
        
                }
                else {
                    callback(null, html);
                }
            });
        };
        let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            service: 'ssl0.ovh.net',
            port : 587,
            secure: false, 
            auth: {
                user: process.env.MAILER_EMAIL,
                pass: process.env.MAILER_PASSWORD
            },
            tls: {
                ciphers:'SSLv3',
                tls:'TLSv1.2',
            }
        });
        readHTMLFile('./Controllers/email/beefree-ec9f8b73xv.html', function (err, html) {
            var template = handlebars.compile(html);
            var replacements = {
                brand: brand,
                model: model,
                date : date,
                id : id
            };
            var htmlToSend = template(replacements);
            var mailOptions = {
                from: process.env.MAILER_EMAIL,
                to: email,
                subject: 'Votre offre a été reçue avec succès',    
                html: htmlToSend
            };
            transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, async (error, response) =>{
               if (error){
                    console.log(error);
                    resolve(false)
                } else {
                    console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
                    resolve(true)
                } 
            });
        });
    })
    
},
```

and im calling it from an API as shown below

```
                offre
                .save()
                .then(result => {
                    
                    mailer.offreEmail(result.brand.toUpperCase(), result.model.toUpperCase(), result.date, result._id, result.email)
                    res.status(200).json(result)
                    photo_name = [];
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    res.status(400).json(error.message)
                    photo_name = [];

                })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i found out that this is not a promise issue,

I added **secureConnection: true,**

And i got rid of both **return new Promise** and the **tls** options  since they both had no effect and i also changed **service** to **host**

Then I started using smtpTransport as shown the code bellow

```
var smtpTransport = require('nodemailer-smtp-transport');

offreEmail : function (brand,model,date,id,email){
    var readHTMLFile = function (path, callback) {
        fs.readFile(path, { encoding: 'utf-8' }, function (err, html) {
            if (err) {
                callback(err);
                throw err;
    
            }
            else {
                callback(null, html);
            }
        });
    };

        var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
            host: 'ssl0.ovh.net', //mail.example.com (your server smtp)
            port: 587, //2525 (specific port)
            secureConnection: true, //true or false
            auth: {
                 user: process.env.MAILER_EMAIL,
                 pass: process.env.MAILER_PASSWORD
            }
        }));

    readHTMLFile('./Controllers/email/beefree-ec9f8b73xv.html', function (err, html) {
        var template = handlebars.compile(html);
        var replacements = {
            brand: brand,
            model: model,
            date : date,
            id : id
        };
        var htmlToSend = template(replacements);
        var mailOptions = {
            from: process.env.MAILER_EMAIL,
            to: email,
            subject: 'Votre offre a été reçue avec succès',    
            html: htmlToSend
        };
        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, response) {
            if (error){
                console.log(error);
            } else {
                console.log('Email sent: ' +response);
            }
        });
    });
},
```